# Adding a list to a one2many

Tags: python, odoo

For my use case,I'm trying to add all the product category list to a contact at creation time.

```
class product_category(models.Model):
            _inherit = "product.category" 
            is_checked = fields.Boolean('Don', help="Check this box if this contact make Donation.")
            resRelId = fields.Many2one('res.partner')

class res_partner(models.Model):
        _inherit = "res.partner"
        categs = fields.One2many('product.category','resRelId',String='Halo')
        @api.model
    def create(self, values):
        categs = self.env['product.category'].search([])
        new_id = super(res_partner, self).create(values)
        for i in categs:
            _logger.error(i)
            new_id.write({'categs': i})
        _logger.error(new_id.categs)
        return new_id
```

My code compile with no errors but i always end up with an empty product list in the contact and I'm getting those warnings.

```
2016-07-04 17:54:46,777 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(1,) == 1 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:800)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,777 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(1,) == 2 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:802)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,777 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(1,) == 3 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:804)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,777 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(1,) == 4 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:812)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,777 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(1,) == 5 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:818)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,778 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(1,) == 6 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:831)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,778 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(3,) == 1 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:800)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,778 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(3,) == 2 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:802)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,778 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(3,) == 3 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:804)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,778 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(3,) == 4 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:812)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,778 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(3,) == 5 (/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py:818)
2016-07-04 17:54:46,778 17751 WARNING v8dev openerp.models: Comparing apples and oranges: product.category(3,) == 6 (/home/odoo/odoo-
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write to a one2many field. That's not how you write to a One2many.

This is a handy tip of various ways of adding and deleting from a one2many:

```
(0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
(1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write *values* on it)
(2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
(3, ID)                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
(4, ID)                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
(5)                    unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
(6, 0, [IDs])          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)
```

The correct way of doing this in your case would be:

```
def create(self, values):
    categs = self.env['product.category'].search([])
    new_id = super(res_partner, self).create(values)
    for i in categs:
        _logger.error(i)
        new_id.write({'categs': (4,i.id)})
    _logger.error(new_id.categs)
    return new_id
```

Comment: I'm having `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. Moreover, I think i can not use (4, ID).
From Odoo 8 documentation:
(4, id, _) adds an existing record of id id to the set. Can not be used on One2many.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easiest way to do this.

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    ## Here categ is a list containing category ids.
    categs = self.env['product.category'].search([]).ids
    values.update({'categs':[(6, 0, categs or [])]})
    return super(res_partner, self).create(values)
```

Comment: Same thing, I'm having TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'.I can not use (6, ID). From Odoo 8 documentation: (6, _, ids) replaces all existing records in the set by the ids list, equivalent to using the command 5 followed by a command 4 for each id in ids. Can not be used on One2many.

Comment: What you have implemented in your code please show us.

Comment: I have updated answer please try this. The value should be list of tuple, like [(6,0,categs)]